# question about absolute value and inequality

Tags: inequality, systems-of-equations, absolute-value

If we have something like
$|\frac{1}{x}|<3$
we now that this is the same as $|x|>\frac{1}{3}$ and we can write solutions as $x<-\frac{1}{3} \lor x> \frac{1}{3}$; but... if I try mecanically to view it as a system of equation like
$$-3<\frac{1}{x}<3\iff\begin{cases}\frac{1}{x}<3\\\frac{1}{x}>-3\end{cases}$$
so working on every equation I have
$$\begin{cases}x>\frac{1}{3}\\x<-\frac{1}{3}\end{cases}$$
that hasn't solutions...
where is my error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first double inequality is an "and" inequality whereas your second double inequality is an "or" inequality.

1. $$ -3<\frac{1}{x} \text{ and } \frac{1}{x}<3 $$
2. $$ x<-\frac{1}{3} \text{ or } x>\frac{1}{3}$$

The **or** enters in the following way:

1. $-3<\dfrac{1}{x}<3$ and since $x$ can be either positive or negative, then
2. Either $-3<\dfrac{1}{x}<0$ **or** $0<\dfrac{1}{x}<3$ therefore
3. Either $-3x>1>0$ **or** $0<1<3x$
4. Either $x<-\dfrac{1}{3}$ **or** $\dfrac{1}{3}<x$

Notice that in steps $(2)$ and $(3)$ multiplication by a negative quantity reverses the sense of the first inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ hence $x \in (-\infty, 0) \cup (0, \infty)$. If $-3 < \frac{1}{x} < 3$ then if $x\in (0,\infty)$ then $-3 < \frac{1}{x}$ $\forall x \in (0,\infty)$. The other condition $\frac{1}{x} < 3$ yields $x > \frac{1}{3}$. Otherwise, if $x \in (-\infty, 0)$ then $\frac{1}{x} < 3$ $\forall x$ and the other condition is $-3 < \frac{1}{x} \Rightarrow 3 > -\frac{1}{x} \Rightarrow x < -\frac{1}{3}$ the sign changes again because $x < 0$. Hence $x \in (-\infty, -\frac{1}{3}) \cup (\frac{1}{3}, \infty)$

Answer (score 0):

i would consider two cases:
$$x>0$$ and we have $$x>\frac{1}{3}$$
in the case of $$x<0$$ we get $$-\frac{1}{x}<3$$ which yields $$x<-\frac{1}{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\frac {1}{x}<3$ doesn't implie that $x>\frac {1}{3} $.
that is your error.

to be true, $x $ must be positive.

so

$$(\frac {1}{x}<3 )\;\;\land \;\;(x>0) \;\implies x>\frac {1}{3} $$